# merge master into subtree branches

Tags: git, git-merge, git-subtree

I have a large Git project which I would like to dissect into subprojects with their own repositories. [Git's subtrees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864475/353337) are ideal for this task: You first

- create a branch with the contents of only one subfolder

  ```
  git subtree split -P <name-of-folder> -b <name-of-new-branch>
  ```

  and then
- pull this branch into another repository.

For a transitional phase, I would like to have the subprojects read-only and *sync* them from master. For every commit to master, I could of course perform the above procedure repeatedly for all subprojects, but this seems less then ideal since it does all the work all over again.

Is there a way to merge master into the subtree branches?

Comment: No there is no way to merge them. I would recommend doing the splits on a  memory backed filesystem in order to speed them up (e.g. `/dev/shm`).  I haven't benchmarked them recently, but I think the `git filter-branch` equivalent of `git subtree split` is faster.